# VB.net file reading tricks?

Tags: vb.net, configuration-files

I'm rather new to VB and I was wondering if you could help me out with something. I've got a file that I need to read and edit, looks something like this:

```
Name|Ted
SetAttackBaseDamage(251,1)
{2|73|10|-1|20,40}
```

I need to be able to load the data here (What will be changing at least) into a variable so that I can change it, almost like what happens in XML except with this. The way the file is set up can't be changed as I'm edit files that are produced by another program, also written in VB.net though it isn't open source.

Comment: Are you having trouble with read the file? Parsing the data? Modifing the data? Writing the data back to the file? or all..

Comment: for the fix pattern .. read per line .. parse it! the pattern is so clear ...

Comment: I can read the file just fine, I need help sorting the data so that it can be viewed and edited by the user, the rest I have got down.

Comment: Ok, but is there always **SetAttackBaseDamage** or could be another text ?

Comment: Yes, The only thing that changes in that line are the two Integer values, "Ted" is the variable for the first line and for the third line everything changes, but there's a constant number of fields.

Comment: You may want to take a look at the TextFieldParser class and see if it will handle your situation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumed that you've 3 line by readline the file .. L1, L2, L3

```
dim sTmp as String

dim sName as String = L1.Split("|")(1) '--> this Name var

sTmp = L2.Split("(")(1) 
dim sSA = split(sTmp.Replace(")", ""),",")
dim sSA1 as String = sSA(0)            '---> this SetAttackBaseDamage - 1
dim sSA2 as String = sSA(1)            '---> this SetAttackBaseDamage - 2
```

just wanna try to help you .. you have to de the rest ............

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much, and here I though Java was the only language that would make setting the split character easy :)